# How to use image in Adaptive Card w/o direct URL to the image

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, adaptive-cards

I would like to use user's profile image from MS graph in adaptive card. I have determined the API call I need to make is as follows

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get

In this case I would be getting image as a binary data for a profile photo, that needs to converted into a base-64 string.

But, based on [adaptive cards schema document](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Image.html) looks like we should use URL property where value should be direct URL to the image

'url string Yes The URL to the image'

How should I approach this ? If there any way to use an IMAGE in Adaptive Card w/o direct URL to the image ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to encode the bytes directly into the payload. Something like [this sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/botframework-csharp-approvalbot-sample/blob/c10a1ec64a93663cb2fab8650192b2e6ef554950/ApprovalBot/Helpers/GraphHelper.cs#L229):

```
var photo = await client.Me.Photos[size].Content.Request().GetAsync();

var photoStream = new MemoryStream();
photo.CopyTo(photoStream);

var photoBytes = photoStream.ToArray();

return string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}",
    Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes));
```

Comment: I think my Question was misunderstood.

How to use image in Adaptive Card w/o direct URL to the image ??

I am not trying to find how to parse image bytes. My question is more on Adaptive Card current capabilities.

Comment: If I've misunderstood then I still misunderstand. I thought you were asking how to embed the image into the card payload. That sample I linked does this. It gets the profile photo from Graph, encodes the binary as base 64, then adds it as a Data URI to the adaptive card.

Comment: I think we both are on same page :) I am using nodejs with following code. Where body is actual response from MS graph. Here is the code. Looks 

`code`
var buffer = require('buffer')
var buf = Buffer.from(body);
var base64String = buf.toString('base64')
"url": "data:image/png;base64,.concat(base64String)
`code`

Looks like base64 conversation isn't correct. Card is not able to render am image.
I uploade an image here :-http://www.dailycoding.com/Utils/Converter/ImageToBase64.aspx

to test. I copied base64 string in URI formate in my card & it worked.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've tried to use data uris in this fashion with adaptive cards and Teams and have had weird results.  The images themselves become "undefined" on Desktop teams and unreadable via the mobile app.